# My web-layer doesn't work when I add any calls to the domain layer in Maven projects

Tags: maven

I have a maven project as a restful design, I separated every layer: I have a domain-layer, data-layer and a web-layer. My problem is: Any time I'm adding a domain class(an entity) to the domain-layer my web-layer doesn't work and I get a 404 exception and nothing more.
I have three projects.

```
1) domain_layer(All entities)
2) data_layer(All service and repositories)
3) web_layer(All controllers).
```

Even I use the commands:

```
mvn clean install eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
```

```
mvn clean package eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
```

doesn't help.

But when I remove the new class it works again.

Any body how knows the problem?

This is my pom.xml in the web-layer:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>....weblayer</groupId>
<artifactId>weblayer</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>SpringMVC Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<!-- Shared version number properties -->
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <org.springframework.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

<!--          all other dependencies-- >


    <!-- dependencies for domain and data-layer -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>domainlayer</groupId>
        <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>datalayer</groupId>
        <artifactId>datalayer</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>


<repositories> 
    <!-- For main Spring releases -->
    <repository>
        <id>org.springframework.maven.release</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <!-- For testing against latest Spring snapshots -->
    <repository>
        <id>org.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <!-- For developing against latest Spring milestones -->
    <repository>
        <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <finalName>weblayer</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <wtpmanifest>true</wtpmanifest>
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                <useProjectReferences>false</useProjectReferences>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any help would be grateful, Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use the commands you give ? On which project ? Both are identical, so I guess there is y typo

Comment: Sorry I updated the question and commands now.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
An @Id was missing in the entity class
Every Entity class must have an @Id annotation.